# how to install docker in sles 12?

Tags: docker, installation, opensuse

I want to install docker stable version in my suse system (version sles 12). For installing docker in suse system, need to add repository of docker.

I didn't found any url (repository url) for adding docker repository of version 1.6. I found docker version 1.12 but it is not working in my case. I removed docker repository now.

can anyone suggest me how I can add correct repository and install docker further in my system?

edit- sample commands and output

**docker -v**

> Docker version 1.6.0, build 4749651

**docker pull hello-world**

> FATA[0000] Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?

**sudo docker pull hello-world**

> sudo: docker: command not found

Answer (score 6):

You can use zypper to do that.

You have to adapt the repository url to your SUSE version. To find the correct package repository, please follow this link
https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=Virtualization%3Acontainers&package=docker

```
sudo zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:containers/openSUSE_Leap_15.0/Virtualization:containers.repo
```

```
sudo zypper dist-upgrade
sudo zypper update
sudo zypper install docker
```

Source : https://w3blog.fr/en/2019/03/25/install-docker-open-source-on-linux-suse/

Comment: Do you know if it is possible install docker-compose on SUSE enterprise 12?

Comment: Yes you can execute : zypper install docker-compose

Answer (score 1):

You will find Docker 1.6 at

https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-1.6.0.tgz

The general doc for installing docker in Suse is available at

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/SUSE/

Comment: @user2915097- yes I will refer that document for installation of docker but can you tell me what is the use of this url i.e tgz file? can you suggest me step wise what I need to do?

Comment: if you download and `tar zxvf` you get the file  /usr/local/bin/docker for docker 1.6 `file usr/local/bin/docker 
usr/local/bin/docker: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=a5773ec80f810b977dc93bb10b4c6c6b8c2b1abd, not stripped`

Comment: @user2915097- ok got it. untar that tgz file. what I need to do after that? I can't directly run **zypper in docker** because repository is not their in my sles 12 system.

Comment: I guess copy it to  /usr/local/bin/ with the correct protections

Comment: @user2915097- copied file in /usr/local/bin/. now docker is executable but how I can run further commands like **systemctl enable docker** , **systemctl start docker** , **sudo docker run hello-world** ?

Comment: from https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/Virtualization:containers/docker  can you find docker 1.6?