# Installation of Docker on Suse Linux SLE 15 SP1

Tags: linux, docker, suse, sles

I am wondering how should I install Docker on SUSE Linux.

I've tried two solutions but neither one works. It gets frustrated a little bit.
The first one is direct install with zypper (provided by SUSE).

```
admin@machine:~> sudo zypper install docker
Refreshing service 'spacewalk'.
Retrieving repository 'sle-manager-tools_vct_prod_15-daicert-x86_64-sp1' metadata ....................................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sle-manager-tools_vct_prod_15-pool-x86_64-sp1' metadata .......................................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sle-manager-tools_vct_prod_15-updates-x86_64-sp1' metadata ....................................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sle-module-basesystem_vct_prod_15-sp1-daicert-x86_64' metadata ................................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sle-module-basesystem_vct_prod_15-sp1-pool-x86_64' metadata ...................................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sle-module-basesystem_vct_prod_15-sp1-updates-x86_64' metadata ................................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sle-module-devtools_vct_prod_15-sp1-daicert-x86_64' metadata ..................................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sle-module-devtools_vct_prod_15-sp1-pool-x86_64' metadata .....................................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sle-module-devtools_vct_prod_15-sp1-updates-x86_64' metadata ..................................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sle-module-server-applications_vct_prod_15-sp1-daicert-x86_64' metadata .......................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sle-module-server-applications_vct_prod_15-sp1-pool-x86_64' metadata ..........................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sle-module-server-applications_vct_prod_15-sp1-updates-x86_64' metadata .......................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sle-product-sles_vct_prod_15-sp1-pool-x86_64' metadata ........................................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sle-product-sles_vct_prod_15-sp1-updates-x86_64' metadata .....................................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sles-15-sp1_vct_prod_dai-os-dai-x86_64' metadata ..............................................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sles-15-sp1_vct_prod_dai-os-daicert-x86_64' metadata ..........................................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sles-15-sp1_vct_prod_dai-os-edc-x86_64' metadata ..............................................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sles-15-sp1_vct_prod_dai-os-flexera-x86_64' metadata ..........................................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'sles-15-sp1_vct_prod_dai-os-tsm-x86_64' metadata ..............................................................................................................................................................[done]
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'docker' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'docker' found.
Resolving package dependencies...
```

The second option, I tried somehow to add the repo which can be found [here](https://software.opensuse.org/ymp/Virtualization:containers/SLE_15_SP1/docker.ymp), but I didn't know how to use the ".repo" extension on this. Somehow like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41136247/how-to-install-docker-in-sles-12). No success.

The other way arround I tried to download a RPM file from their website and get it on the machine.

```
admin@machine:~> rpm -i docker-19.03.5_ce-371.1.x86_64.rpm
warning: docker-19.03.5_ce-371.1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 72174fc2: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        apparmor-parser is needed by docker-19.03.5_ce-371.1.x86_64
        catatonit is needed by docker-19.03.5_ce-371.1.x86_64
        containerd-git = b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339 is needed by docker-19.03.5_ce-371.1.x86_64
        docker-libnetwork-git = 3eb39382bfa6a3c42f83674ab080ae13b0e34e5d is needed by docker-19.03.5_ce-371.1.x86_64
        docker-runc-git = 3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657 is needed by docker-19.03.5_ce-371.1.x86_64
        fix_bsc_1057743 is needed by docker-19.03.5_ce-371.1.x86_64
        iptables >= 1.4 is needed by docker-19.03.5_ce-371.1.x86_64
```

No success as well.
Any solution here?

Answer (score 1):

This answer probably arrives too late, but at least for the sake of completeness: Your system seems to be missing the "Containers Module". This module/repository should contain everything you need to get started.

For detailed instructions, please have a look at the official documentation:
https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP1/single-html/SLES-dockerquick/index.html#id-1.13.3.2.4

Comment: Never too late. I didn't progress with the installation there and let it over the client's hands. I had a lot. Will try this approach. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CupRacer I am facing similar issue. As per document trying this command "sudo SUSEConnect -p sle-module-containers/15.1/x86_64 -r ''"  but it is getting timeout.

Comment: @Anil If this timeout is not caused by a general network issue: Do you need to use a proxy to reach destinations outside your (corporate?) network?

Comment: Please also note that SLES 15 SP1 is out of general support and you should consider using SP4 instead. If you are allowed to use an LTSS subscription, please activate it and upgrade your system packages as well.